# How to allow async functions in React + Babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a Typescript/React app, that can perform async function with a then/catch promise, but not with async/await/try/catch.

The error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined .

The error seems to come from Babel. Here is my config:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find your solution at [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8829#issuecomment-456524916)

If I summarise then you have to install a `babel` plugin named `plugin-transform-runtime` and need to configure the `.babelrc` settings.

```
npm install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime --save-dev
npm install @babel/runtime
```

After installing these two go to the `.babelrc` file and add these plugins.

```
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! For anyone using webpack, make sure that you don't put this into your `webpack.config.js`, it needs to go only in your `.babel.rc`.

Answer (score 3):

for babel 7

***All necessary packages are included in "@babel/preset-env"***

[image]

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "10.0.0"
                }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

**Super Basic example**

```
import React from "react";

const Board = () => {

    const [resp_post, setResp_post] = React.useState(0);

    (async function getData() {
        setResp_post(await Promise.resolve(30));
    })();
    
    return <h1>Board {resp_post} {value}</h1>;
};

export default Board;
```

[preset-env documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env)

[preset-reactlink documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)

Comment: `"targets": { "node": "10.0.0" }` saved my life, thank you! Also can be set to `{ targets: { node: true } }`.

Comment: the exact document came from this link: but it is not very well explained for nodejs: I hope you can expand your knowledge with this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#targets