# Babel 7 - Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` using React with webpack and Babel .

[image]

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755999/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-react) by defining my `.babel.rc` as:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] ,
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
  ]
}
```

and running:

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

However, I get the exact same error afterwards. I've also followed [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65487071/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-react-17-webpack) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304124/how-to-allow-async-functions-in-react-babel), but still get the exact same error.

My babel specific installations in `package.json` are as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5"
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

hey I ran into the same problem and I am using Babel 7, for me I installed these two dependencies:

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

And, in .babelrc, add:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
  ]
}
```

**and this solved my problem**

Comment: Is the closing curly bracket missing?

Comment: @WillLanni  The closing bracket was separated from the code, but I just fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

> {   "presets": [
> [
> **"@babel/preset-env",
> {
> "targets": {
> "node": "9.2.1"
> }
> }**
> ],
> "@babel/preset-react"   ] }

This is my file **.babelrc**

Look:

@babel/preset-env is a smart preset that allows you to use the latest JavaScript without needing to micromanage which syntax transforms (and optionally, browser **polyfills**) are needed by your target environment(s). This both makes your life easier and JavaScript bundles smaller!

**your problemes:**

You are using "@ babel / preset-env" you must specify the version of node to compile. "node> 7.6". I recommend 10.

Why **node > 7.6** *Node.js 7.6 has shipped with official support for async/await enabled by default and better performance on low-memory devices.*

**How do you specify the version: It's simple**

targets.node
string | "current".

```
If you want to compile against the current node version, you can specify "node": "current", which would be the same as "node": process.versions.node.
```

AND FOR ME LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "9.2.1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

This allows the compiler to understand ASYNC AWAIT, hope it helps you!

**You can also add a plugin to handle your "asyc away"**

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator

[image: ATENTION - > This Config is for node-js it is just a example]

- 

> ATTENTION - > This Config is for node-js; it is just a example

- 

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

[How to allow async functions in React + Babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304124/how-to-allow-async-functions-in-react-babel)

My problem was that I was defining the babel plugin in *both* my `.babel.rc` file and my `webpack.config.js` file. I needed to remove that plugin from my `webpack.config.js` and simply use it only in my `.babel.rc` file. Then it worked well.